# What is a word for "bringing someone over to your side of the argument"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for "bringing someone over to your side of the argument"?

> By doing so Enoch ____ [the audience]

What I want transmitted: By doing so Enoch ***makes his audience believe him*** ...

**Edit:** I should note that the reader has no opinion yet...

Based on responses this is what I currently have:

> By doing so swaying the audience his way right from the start.

Comment: convince is a natural candidate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**win over**

> By doing so Enoch **won** the audience **over**.

You can also try **sway**:

> By doing so Enoch **swayed** the audience.

Comment: I was just researching this but your answer needs a bit of support, such as this [Lexico entry](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/win) for **win someone over**.

Answer (score 1):

How about - "***Bring around***"?

## Bring around

> To prompt one to change their opinion or view on something.
>
> *I've found that political debates at dinner parties rarely bring someone around to a different point of view.*

([Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+around))

Therefore -

> *By doing so, Enoch **brought around** [the audience].*

---

The above is a phrasal verb. A single word could be -

## Induce

> : succeed in persuading or leading (someone) to do something.

([Source](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/induce))

Therefore -

> *By doing so, Enoch **induced** [the audience].*

Answer (score 1):

He **persuaded** the audience:

> to move by argument, entreaty, or expostulation to a belief, position, or course of action —[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persuade)

Another good synonym is **convince**.

Answer (score 0):

**bring (one) over**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+over) an idiom

bring (one) over

- > To sway one's loyalties.

And [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bring-over) lists **bring over** as a verb (phrase)

> My aunt is determined to bring me over to her political party,
>   ignoring the fact that I am not remotely interested in changing sides!